# Скачет значение функции ошибки (loss function)

Tags: python, python-3.x, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Из-за чего могут так скакать лосовские функции?

```
def get_model():

  model = Sequential()

  model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',
                                     input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
  model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
  #model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))

  model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
  #model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))

  model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2))


  model.add(layers.Flatten())

  model.add(layers.Dense(120, activation='relu')) 
  model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))

  model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))

  model.add(layers.Dense(10,activation='relu')) 

  model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

  return model
```

[image: Результат после 20 эпох]

Answer (score 1):

На это влияет как минимум три фактора:

1. размер батча - `batch_size`, чем меньше его размер, тем больше колебания.
2. регуляризация (в вашем случае `Dropout()` слои) увеличивают значения функции ошибки как для обучающей так и для проверочной выборок.
3. при переобучении значения функции ошибки увеличиваются только для проверочной выборки.